# What version of libraries to link against in a kext's OSBundleLibraries?

Tags: macos, kernel-extension

I ran `kextlibs` against my kext, and it told me to use:

```
com.apple.kpi.bsd = 12.2
com.apple.kpi.libkern = 12.2
```

this runs fine on my development machine (10.8). But when I run it on another machine (running 10.7) it doesn't load, saying:

```
Dependency Resolution Failures: 
Only incompatible kexts found for these libraries: 
    com.apple.kpi.bsd
    com.apple.kpi.libkern
```

How do I work out which versions to link against if I want to target a range of Mac OS versions (10.6 to 10.8)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The KPI "bundles" (com.apple.kpi.*) are versioned by the Kernel's Darwin version number.

- The Darwin major number is the OSX minor number plus 4 - so OSX 10.8 is Darwin 12, 10.7 is 11, 10.6 is 10, etc. (this is at least true going back to OSX 10.4, I don't have any experience with 10.3 or older)
- The Darwin minor number is the OSX revision number - so OSX 10.8.2 is Darwin 12.2, OSX 10.6.8 is Darwin 10.8, OSX 10.7 is Darwin 11.0 etc. (An OSX/macOS revision occasionally increments by more than one Darwin minor version, for example macOS 10.14.**1** is Darwin 18.**2**.0.)

The IOKit Families (e.g. IOPCIFamily, IOStorageFamily, etc.) have their own versioning schemes. The way to handle these is to look at the bundle version (CFBundleVersion) property in the Info.plist in the relevant kext (IOPCIFamily.kext, IOStorageFamily.kext, etc.) for the oldest OSX version you want to support. Or, just run kextlibs while running that OS version - kextlibs will always print the kext/kpi version numbers for the running version of OSX.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a go. Does the kernel have a number simultaneously running historical ABIs to link against (sorry if that's not quite the right language)? And is there a list of backward compatibility? Is it possible to have something that works with both 10.8 and 10.6? Is there a published (or discoverable) list?

Comment: @Joe the [Kernel Framework Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/Mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/KernelIOKitFramework/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000816) will sometimes tell you version availability for a function/method, and/or there might be a comment by the declaration in the header file. For example, [the documentation for `IOStorage::unmap()`](http://developer.apple.com/library/Mac/documentation/Kernel/Reference/IOStorage_reference/translated_content/IOStorage.html#//apple_ref/cpp/instm/IOStorage/unmap/IOReturn) doesn't mention version, but the header says 10.6.6.

Comment: Most of the parts of the kernel where the APIs you can actually use are implemented are actually open source, and this source code is [available for every OSX release](http://www.opensource.apple.com/). So if in doubt, this is the authoritative information. The main kernel package is 'xnu', but there are separate source packages for various areas of the IOKit, file systems, etc. Note that API availability also depends on CPU architecture/bits, so if you're targeting 10.6 you'll almost certainly want to support 32-bit kernels - make sure to disable 'build active architecture only' in Xcode.

Comment: You should generally expect to refer to the kernel headers and source frequently, as much of the API isn't documented. Finally, there is no substitute for actually going ahead and testing on the versions in question. I find it helpful to use virtual machines if I can (obviously doesn't help if it's a driver for a physical device). Often you'll find that different versions behave subtly differently, or will kernel panic on innocent-looking API calls that work in other versions.

Comment: If you want a comprehensive list of published symbols for a particular version, you can collect all the .exports files from the source packages. You can conveniently diff those between versions. And in case it's not clear, it is entirely possible to support a large range of versions from a single kext. In some cases, you can also weakly link against newer APIs and test for their presence at runtime.

Comment: Thanks very much, brilliantly helpful.